# Adding footer to existing PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to add footer to my existing PDF. I did add one footer to the PDF.

Is there anyway to add 2 lines of footer? This is my code below:

```
Document document = new Document(); 

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/TestDestination/Merge Output1.pdf")));
document.open();

PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("D:/TestDestination/Merge Output.pdf");
int n1 = reader1.getNumberOfPages();

PdfImportedPage page;
PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 5, Font.ITALIC);

for (int i = 0; i < n1; ) {
    page = copy.getImportedPage(reader1, ++i);
    stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER,new Phrase(String.format("page %d of %d", i, n1)),297.5f, 28, 0);
    stamp.alterContents();
    copy.addPage(page);
}

document.close();
reader1.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to [the official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and click [Q&A](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions) to go to the Frequently Asked Questions. Select [Absolute positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text).

You are currently using `ColumnText` in a way that allows you to add a single line of text. You are using `ColumnText.showTextAligned(...)` as explained in my answer to the question [How to rotate a single line of text?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-single-line-text)

You should read the answers to questions such as:

- [How to add text at an absolute position on the top of the first page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-absolute-position-top-first-page)
- [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle)
- [How to truncate text within a bounding box?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-truncate-text-within-bounding-box)
- [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fit-string-inside-rectangle)
- [How to reduce redundant code when adding content at absolute positions?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-reduce-redundant-code-when-adding-content-absolute-positions)

Assuming that you don't have access to the official web site (otherwise you wouldn't have posted your question), I'm adding a short code snippet:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamp.getUnderContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(rectangle);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph("Whatever text needs to fit inside the rectangle"));
ct.go();
```

In this snippet, `stamp` is the object you created in your code. The `rectangle` object is of type `Rectangle`. Its parameters are the coordinates of the lower-left and upper-right corner of the rectangle in which you want to render the multi-line text.

**Caveat:** all text that doesn't fit the `rectangle` will be dropped. You can avoid this by adding the text in simulation mode first. If the text fits, add it for real. If it doesn't fit, try anew using a smaller font or a bigger rectangle.

Comment: i tried a lot in finding about adding paragraphs  as a header or footer.This syntax worked out well!!!. Kudos to you bruno!!!